# Which one is correct? (Which)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the differences between these 3 sentences?

1. She is very arrogant **, which** I don't think she has a flexible personality.
2. She is very arrogant **;** I don't think she has a flexible personality.
3. She is very arrogant **, and** I don't think she has a flexible personality.

Someone told me that the first one is wrong.
But why?

And what is the differences between the first one and ''*I think the other thing that was really good about it as well was that everybody worked really hard and helped tidy up at the end **, which** I hadn't expected at all.*''?

Comment: #1 would make sense with the following correction: She is very arrogant, which is why I don't think she has a flexible personality. 
Or even better: She is very arrogant, which is why I think she has an inflexible personality.

Answer (score 3):

1. Which is definitely not used as an "interrogative pronoun" as it is not leading an interrogative sentence there. It can only function as [Relative Pronoun](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns). It is well explained in a concise manner in the link. You had better visit the link. In the sentence, "which" doesn't have an antecedent that it can replace and there is no place in the 2nd independent clause where it can fit. That's why this sentence is wrong.

   [Antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)) can be a word, phrase, **clause**, etc. that gives its meaning to a pro-form (pronoun, pro-verb, pro-adverb, etc.) as well-explained in the link. The last example is correct (I don't want' to proof-read it) in terms of using which, as *an antecedent of which* is the previous clause which is an object of ***expected*** in the second clause.
2. It is a grammatical rule that you have to have a conjunction after comma if you want to construct a compound sentence. Instead of comma and conjunction, you can use [**semi-colon**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semicolon), but it is only used when you need clearer separation than would be shown by a comma,  which is well explained in Merriam-Webster. I don't think the *semi-colon* used in the sentence is absolutely necessary. You can use just **"comma + and**".
3. As explained in No. 2

Answer (score 1):

"Which" is a pronoun, not a conjunction.

In your first sentence, the second clause has two subjects: "which" and "I". That doesn't make sense.

You could say, "She is very arrogant, which is unpleasant". Here "which" is referring back to her arrogance. This would be equivalent to saying, "She is very arrogant. Her arrogance is unpleasant."

Or you might say, "She is very arrogant, which leads me to think that she does not have a flexible personality" or something of that sort.

But you can't substitute "which" for a conjunction like "and" or "but", because it's not a conjunction.

Sentences 2 and 3 are good. You can connect two independent clauses -- that is, two clauses each of which could be a sentence on its own -- with a conjunction like "and", or with a semi-colon. Either is valid.

Comment: Why having two subjects in a clause not make any sense?

Comment: @Usernew Let me clarify that there's a difference between a compound subject and two subjects. That is, if you say "Bob and my sister run the committee", that's perfectly valid. The two of them are both doing this task. But if you said "Bob my sister run the committee", there are two subjects, "Bob" and "my sister", and it is not clear what you mean. Does Bob run the committee? Does my sister run the committee? Are "Bob" and "my sister" the same person? Does one of them run the committee and the other do something else? Etc.

Comment: what about this: "I bought a new dress, which I will be wearing to Jo's party." [Source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/that-or-which)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see the issue. In that sentence, "which" is introducing a clause that is acting as an adjective. In that clause, "which" is not the subject but the object. Note that "which" is not wearing anything, it is "I" who am wearing something. What am I wearing? I am wearing "which", that is, the thing referred to earlier, the "new dress". In such clauses we always begin with "which" to identify the clause, but in context it can be either a subject or an object. "I bought a new dress, which I will be wearing". "I" is the subject, "which" is the object. But "I bought a new dress, which ...

Comment: ... impressed my boyfriend". Now "which" is the subject and "my boyfriend" is the object.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments about version 1.
The difference between 2 and 3 is that 2 suggests that her arrogance is a consequence of her inflexible personality, whereas 3 could be interpreted that these are two separate traits that are not necessarily caused by or consequent on each other.